# Is there a webhook in CloudKit?

Tags: swift, push-notification, cloudkit

I like CloudKit a lot for Apple purposes. However my app also likes to connect with Android users. So if there was a way my server could be aware that something changed in the Cloud container (without constantly querying the database if something is new) that would be awesome, because then I could send a notification to Android users as well.

Comment: [This](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02042016a) might be what you want.

Comment: Yea I found that and it's great news. However I can only manage subscriptions I didn't read how my web server could know of any changes happening. Perhaps I am missing something.